# Why did the EPA/NHSTA decide on 1.5% FE/CO2 increases for LDV and light trucks in its final SAFE ruling?

Tags: vehicle

In their final [ruling](https://www.epa.gov/sites/production/files/2020-03/documents/final-fr-safe-preamble-033020.pdf), the EPA/NHSTA settled on alternative #3, where LDV (light duty vehicles)/light trucks are required to increase their fuel economy and reduce CO2 by 1.5% per year. There are 8 total alternatives, plus the base case proposed by Obama administration in 2011. The document is nearly 2,000 pages. I have read a lot of it. What I can't understand is their rationale for choosing alternative 3. They spend a ton of time discussing and showing charts, but the charts don't point to alternative 3 being the best! See the summary of the charts below. Does anyone know *where* in the document I can find an explanation of this? A "alternative 3 does not have the highest net benefits but it was chosen anyway because..." is the sort of thing I am looking for. They seem to just display the information and then assert that they have chosen alternative 3.[image: 7]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://politics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @BlueDogRanch what how? It has nothing to do with politics? I am asking where in the document their rationale is because I want to read it. I am not suggesting it's not there or that their decision is politically motivated?

Comment: I don't think it is in one place. If you read the executive summary and focus on the parts that talk about 1.5% you get "the reasons", but not an explicit comparison to all other alternatives, e.g. "standards that increase at 1.5 percent per year for cars and trucks will help to keep fleet fuel economy higher than they would be otherwise when fuel prices are low". §VI discussed analytical methodology.

Comment: @user6726 that was my understanding too, I was just polling in case I had missed it. Given how in depth they discuss just about everything else, it seemed odd that they didn't actually say "this is why we made the decision" via comparing the selected alternative to the others.